# MPAndroidChart - animations between real-time data points

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am currently using MPAndroidChart to display real-time data. I have been able to add points to a line chart and update a radar chart with the data. However, I am having issues with implementing smooth animations when updating the charts.

So, for example, instead of just redrawing the line chart to include a new point of data, I would like the line to gradually extend to a new data point, sliding to the right if an old data point is being replaced (when outside of the visible axis range). And in the radar chart, if a point of data changes from, say, 20 to 60, I would like the point on the chart to smoothly move from the 20 to 60 instead of the chart being completely redrawn.

At the moment, I have found the animateX, animateY, and animateXY methods in the library. However, these only seem to be for initially creating the chart. I need there to be animations while data is continually added to an existing chart. Is it possible with this library? What kinds of tweaks would I need to make?

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: I have not used this library since last year, but I didn't end up finding a way to animate what I wanted

Comment: @Christian did you find any solution to this.

Comment: Did you found a library that does this?